# Inequality in Mysql with count()

Tags: mysql, sql, count, many-to-many

I have the following structure :

```
Table Author :
idAuthor,
Name 

+----------+-------+
| idAuthor | Name  |
+----------+-------+
|        1 | Renee |
|        2 | John  |
|        3 | Bob   |
|        4 | Bryan |
+----------+-------+
Table Publication:
idPublication,
Title,
Type,
Date,
Journal,
Conference
+---------------+--------------+------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| idPublication | Title        | Date | Type        | Conference | Journal   |
+---------------+--------------+------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|             1 | Flower thing | 2008 | book        | NULL       | NULL      |
|             2 | Bees         | 2009 | article     | NULL       | Le Monde  |
|             3 | Wasps        | 2010 | inproceding | KDD        | NULL      |
|             4 | Whales       | 2010 | inproceding | DPC        | NULL      |
|             5 | Lyon         | 2011 | article     | NULL       | Le Figaro |
|             6 | Plants       | 2012 | book        | NULL       | NULL      |
|             7 | Walls        | 2009 | proceeding  | KDD        | NULL      |
|             8 | Juices       | 2010 | proceeding  | KDD        | NULL      |
|             9 | Fruits       | 2010 | proceeding  | DPC        | NULL      |
|            10 | Computers    | 2010 | inproceding | DPC        | NULL      |
|            11 | Phones       | 2010 | inproceding | DPC        | NULL      |
|            12 | Creams       | 2010 | proceeding  | DPC        | NULL      |
|            13 | Love         | 2010 | proceeding  | DPC        | NULL      |
+---------------+--------------+------+-------------+------------+-----------+

Table author_has_publication :
Author_idAuthor,
Publication_idPublication
+-----------------+---------------------------+
| Author_idAuthor | Publication_idPublication |
+-----------------+---------------------------+
|               1 |                         1 |
|               2 |                         2 |
|               3 |                         3 |
|               4 |                         4 |
|               1 |                         5 |
|               2 |                         5 |
|               3 |                         5 |
|               3 |                         6 |
|               4 |                         7 |
|               4 |                         8 |
|               4 |                         9 |
|               4 |                        10 |
|               3 |                        11 |
|               3 |                        12 |
|               2 |                        13 |
+-----------------+---------------------------+
```

I want to obtain the list of all authors having published at least 2 times at conference DPC in 2010. 
I achieved to get the list of autors that have published something, and the number of publication for each, but I can't get my 'at least 2' factor.

My following query

```
SELECT author.name, COUNT(name) FROM author INNER JOIN author_has_publication ON author.idAuthor=author_has_publication.Author_idAuthor INNER JOIN publication ON author_has_publication.Publication_idPublication=publication.idPublication AND publication.date=2010 AND publication.conference='DPC'GROUP BY author.name;
```

returns the following result (which is good)

```
+-------+-------------+
| name  | COUNT(name) |
+-------+-------------+
| Bob   |           2 |
| Bryan |           3 |
| John  |           1 |
+-------+-------------+
```

but when I try to select only the one with a count(name)>=2, i got an error.
I tried this query :

```
SELECT author.name, COUNT(name) FROM author INNER JOIN author_has_publication ON author.idAuthor=author_has_publication.Author_idAuthor INNER JOIN publication ON author_has_publication.Publication_idPublication=publication.idPublication AND publication.date=2010 AND publication.conference='DPC'GROUP BY author.name WHERE COUNT(name)>=2;
```

Comment: Change your `WHERE` to `HAVING` and I think you'll be done.

Comment: You were true ! why where is not working in that case ?

Comment: Because WHERE comes before GROUP BY.

Comment: Ok ! I tried to put my WHERE statement before but I got an error saying 'invalid use fo group function'

Answer (score 1):

When you use aggregation funcion you can filter with a proper operator named HAVING

Having worok on the result of the query (then pn the aggrgated result like count() ) instead of where that work on  the original value of the tables rows

```
SELECT author.name, COUNT(name) 
FROM author INNER JOIN author_has_publication 
        ON author.idAuthor=author_has_publication.Author_idAuthor 
INNER JOIN publication 
       ON author_has_publication.Publication_idPublication=publication.idPublication 
AND publication.date=2010 AND publication.conference='DPC'
GROUP BY author.name 
HAVING COUNT(name)>=2;
```